# How to add Gmagick class(Load library) to Codeception?

Tags: codeception, gmagick

I'm trying to use Gmagick from codeception, and i get:

```
[Error] Class 'Helper\Gmagick' not found
```

or if i try calling Gmagick(); directly from the test:

```
[Error] Class 'Gmagick' not found
```

I've set up Gmagick and can use it i.e. if i create a standalone *.php file on my apache server, i can call Gmagick(); without ever declaring anything else.

If I try the same from within Codeception, I get aforementioned error. I suppose there's some simple fix to this but I can't get any useful info from Codeception's documentation, and i can't find any useful info on the internet/SO either.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You :)

Comment: I think that you have gmagick enabled in apache's php.ini file, but not in cli php.ini file.  Run php -m to confirm.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was actually the problem!